# searching a specific values from one file in another file using nested for loop

Tags: python, if-statement, readfile, nested-for-loop

I have two files, file A.txt has hundreds of rows of format (ip,mac) and file B.txt has hundreds of rows of format (mac). what I am looking for is to search the (macs) from file B in file A and if found to print the line (ip, mac) from file A. there are already more than 100 mac matches between the two files but with the code I wrote it returns only the first match.

below is my simple code

```
with open("B.txt", "r") as out_mac_file, open("A.txt", "r") as out_arp_file:
    for x in out_mac_file:
        for y in out_arp_file:
            if x in y:
                print(y)
```

Any idea what could be wrong in the code, or if there other ways to do that?

Edit: Adding the format of file A and file B

File B

```
64167f18cd3d
64167f18c77a
64167f067082
64167f0670b5
64167f067400
64167f0674e5
64167f06740d
```

File A

```
10.55.14.160,64167f869f18
10.55.20.59,64167f37a5f4
10.55.20.62,64167f8866e0
10.55.20.65,64167f8b4bd8
10.55.20.66,64167f372a72
10.55.20.67,64167f371436
```

Comment: Can you show us the format (few lines) from B.txt and A.txt please

Comment: I have added it to the main question, thank you!

Comment: What's the code's current behavior?

Comment: Thank you @user202729. the seek(0) method did the trick. now I got the list of matches :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using pandas (since your data is in coma separated format):

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv("A.txt", header=None, names=["mac"])
b = pd.read_csv("B.txt", header=None, names=["ip","mac"])

for mac in a["mac"]:
  result = b[b["mac"] == mac]
  if len(result) > 0:
    print (result)
```

Or just a oneliner instead of a loop:

```
b.merge(a, on="mac")
```

Comment: Thank you!  I added one line in the code with the seek(0) method, however this worth trying also. good to always have alternatives.